# Local charge density manipulation of ionized air

Tags: electrostatics, ions, gas

Assume we have ionized the air in an isolated container. Would is be possible to concentrate the ions within a specific region of the container with electric fields, i.e. to manipulate local charge density levels?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   Something similar happens routinely around the electrodes (the cathode) of a vacuum tube, in the electron gas created from
the heated cathode.  It's called 'space charge'.   Usually, though, this means electrodes will be absorbing charge from the ions, because the charge moves naturally from small ions to large ions, to any larger objects that are
present.  Unless those larger objects (your electrodes) REPEL the
ions, they'll collect charge fast, and you'll have to replace it. 
A useful device, the 'dekatron', was a kind of gas-filled tube that
implemented logic functions by moving an ionization region with electrodes.

Ion beams are created/focused/accelerated in a variety of useful
devices (atomic clocks, for instance).

On short timescales (or with large distances between gas molecules) you can
also manipulate uncharged ionized gas (with mixed + and - charges); this comes under the general term 'magnetohydrodynamics' and has been extensively studied.